# Error when running BYFN end to end test on hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When running the byfn end-to-end test I'm getting the following errors, this is in response to the command ./byfn.sh -m up

Any suggestions please on how to resolve this, many thanks, Rak
 ____    _____      _      ____    _____ 
Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test

Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ID=cli
CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
./scripts/script.sh: line 64: peer: command not found
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

Answer (score 0):

> export PATH=path to download location/bin:$PATH

You are missing this path location after installing your binaries. This should do it.

Comment: where exactly would you write export PATH=downloaddir/bin:$PATH .... I am new to terminal, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that in the [documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.5/samples.html) for running the samples, you first clone **fabric-samples** and then cd into the directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git
cd fabric-samples
```

After that, you run the script to download the images and binaries.

This results in the binaries being placed in the fabric-samples/bin  directory and this is added to the PATH and the bfn script can find them.  If you did not follow the above instructions and you downloaded the binaries in another directory, then you'll need to set the PATH environment variable:

**export PATH=downloaddir/bin:$PATH**

as mentioned in the comment above

Comment: Thanks all, as per the documentation I did

Comment: where exactly would you write export PATH=downloaddir/bin:$PATH .... I am new to terminal, thank you. @Rak